# Blinking LEDs in sequence with a class

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to make a program that accepts four digit password using a 3*4 keypad.

The program should start with flashing LED1 and when password 1 is entered it switches this LED and blinks LED2. If password 2 is entered it switches to LED3 and so on.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <TimedBlink.h>

#define Password_Length 5

TimedBlink led1(14);
TimedBlink led2(15);
TimedBlink led3(16);
TimedBlink led4(17);

const unsigned long PERIOD1 = 1000;
char  buffers[4][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4'}, {'6', '5', '4', '3'}, {'9', '8', '7', '6'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6'}}; // this is how to initialise a 2d array
unsigned long previousMillis[5]; //[x] = number of leds
char Data[Password_Length]; // 6 is the number of chars it can hold + the null char = 7

byte data_count = 0;
bool Pass_is_good;
char customKey;

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
int ledservos[4] = {14, 15, 16, 17};
Keypad customKeypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); //initialize an instance of class NewKeypad

void setup() {
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT);
  led1.blink(150, 50); // On for 150ms, off for 50ms
  led2.blink(150, 50);
  led3.blink(150, 50); // On for 150ms, off for 50ms
  led4.blink(150, 50);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Enter Password");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  led1.blink();
  led2.blink();
  led3.blink();
  led4.blink();
  customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  if (customKey) {
  // makes sure a key is actually pressed, equal to (customKey != NO_KEY)
    Data[data_count] = customKey; // store char into data array
    data_count++; // increment data array by 1 to store new char, also keep track of the number of chars entered
  }
  if (data_count == Password_Length - 1) {
    // if the array index is equal to the number of expected chars, compare data to master
    Serial.print("Password is ");
    for (byte i = 0; i < Password_Length; i++)
      Serial.print(Data[i]);
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) { //this loop for number of passwords in the array
      for (y = 0; y < 4; y ++) { //this loop for number of characters in each of the password array
        if (strcmp(Data[y], buffers[x][y]) != 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (y == 4) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (x < 4) {
      Serial.print(" Found at index ");
      Serial.println(x);
      switch (x) {
        case 0:
          led1.blinkOff();
          break;
        case 1:
          led2.blinkOff();
          break;
        case 2:
          led3.blinkOff();
          break;
        case 3:
          led4.blinkOff();
          break;
      }
    }
    clearData();
  }
}

void clearData() {
  Serial.println();
  while (data_count != 0) {
    // This can be used for any array size,
    Data[data_count--] = 0; //clear array for new data
  }
}

void BlinkLed (int led, int interval, int arry) {
  //(long) can be omitted if you dont plan to blink led for very long time I think
  if (((long)millis() - previousMillis[arry]) >= interval) {
    previousMillis[arry] = millis(); //stores the millis value in the selected array
    digitalWrite(led, !digitalRead(led)); //changes led state
  }
}
```

Now I can make the program, but all LEDs start blinking and switch off after the password is entered and I got stuck at this point.

Here is a link to the [TimedBlink](https://github.com/lpasqualis/TimedBlink) Library.

I have tried the `millis()` function to be used to blink LEDs in the next code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define buzzer 13
#define greenled 20
#define redled 21
#define Password_Length 5

unsigned long previousMillisLED14 = 0;
unsigned long previousMillisLED15 = 0;
unsigned long previousMillisLED16 = 0;
unsigned long previousMillisLED17 = 0;
// different intervals for each LED
int intervalLED14 = 500;
int intervalLED15 = 600;
int intervalLED16 = 700;
int intervalLED17 = 800;
// each LED gets a state varaible
boolean LED14state = false;     // the LED will turn ON in the first iteration of loop()
boolean LED15state = false;     // need to seed the light to be OFF
boolean LED16state = false;     // need to seed the light to be OFF
boolean LED17state = false;     // need to seed the light to be OFF
const unsigned long PERIOD1 = 1000;
char  buffers[4][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4'}, {'6', '5', '4', '3'}, {'9', '8', '7', '6'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6'}}; // this is how to initialise a 2d array
unsigned long previousMillis[5]; //[x] = number of leds
byte i, x, y;
char Data[Password_Length]; // 6 is the number of chars it can hold + the null char = 7
byte data_count = 0;
bool Pass_is_good;
char customKey;
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
int ledservos[4] = {14, 15, 16, 17};
Keypad customKeypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); //initialize an instance of class NewKeypad

void setup() {
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT);
  Serial.print("Enter Password");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillisLED14) >= intervalLED14) {
    LED14state = !LED14state;
    digitalWrite(14, LED14state);
    // save current time to pin 12's previousMillis
    previousMillisLED14 = currentMillis;
  }
  customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  if (customKey) {
    // makes sure a key is actually pressed, equal to (customKey != NO_KEY)
    Data[data_count] = customKey; // store char into data array
    data_count++; // increment data array by 1 to store new char, also keep track of the number of chars entered
  }
  if (data_count == Password_Length - 1) {
    // if the array index is equal to the number of expected chars, compare data to master
    Serial.print("Password is ");
    for (byte i = 0; i < Password_Length; i++)
      Serial.print(Data[i]);
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      //this loop for number of passwords in the array
      for (y = 0; y < 4; y ++) {
        //this loop for number of characters in each of the password array
        if (strcmp(Data[y], buffers[x][y]) != 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (y == 4) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (x < 4) {
      Serial.print(" Found at index ");
      Serial.println(x);
      switch (x) {
        case 0:
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(16, LOW);
          digitalWrite(17, LOW);
          if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillisLED15) >= intervalLED15) {
            LED15state = !LED15state;
            digitalWrite(15, LED15state);
            // save current time to pin 12's previousMillis
            previousMillisLED15 = currentMillis;
          }
          break;
        case 1:
          digitalWrite(15, LOW);
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(17, LOW);
          if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillisLED16) >= intervalLED16) {
            LED16state = !LED16state;
            digitalWrite(16, LED15state);
            // save current time to pin 12's previousMillis
            previousMillisLED16 = currentMillis;
          }
          break;
        case 2:
          digitalWrite(15, LOW);
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(16, LOW);
          if ((unsigned long)(currentMillis - previousMillisLED17) >= intervalLED17) {
            LED17state = !LED17state;
            digitalWrite(17, LED17state);
            // save current time to pin 12's previousMillis
            previousMillisLED17 = currentMillis;
          }
          break;
        case 3:
          digitalWrite(15, LOW);
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(16, LOW);
          digitalWrite(17, LOW);
          break;
      }
    }
    clearData();
  }
}

void clearData() {
  Serial.println();
  while (data_count != 0) {
    // This can be used for any array size,
    Data[data_count--] = 0; //clear array for new data
  }
}
```

But it blinks the first LED only, then each of the following LEDs according to the condition got permanent on.
I have tried the solution that Adafruit suggested, to use a class in code but unfortunately I got the same result as the previous code.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>

class Flasher {
    // Class Member Variables
    // These are initialized at startup
    int ledPin;      // the number of the LED pin
    long OnTime;     // milliseconds of on-time
    long OffTime;    // milliseconds of off-time
    // These maintain the current state
    int ledState;                 // ledState used to set the LED
    unsigned long previousMillis;   // will store last time LED was updated
    // Constructor - creates a Flasher
    // and initializes the member variables and state
  public:
    Flasher(int pin, long on, long off) {
      ledPin = pin;
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
      OnTime = on;
      OffTime = off;
      ledState = LOW;
      previousMillis = 0;
    }
    void Update() {
      // check to see if it's time to change the state of the LED
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
      if ((ledState == HIGH) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OnTime)) {
        ledState = LOW;  // Turn it off
        previousMillis = currentMillis;  // Remember the time
        digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);  // Update the actual LED
      } else if ((ledState == LOW) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OffTime)) {
        ledState = HIGH;  // turn it on
        previousMillis = currentMillis;   // Remember the time
        digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);   // Update the actual LED
      }
    }
};

Flasher led1(14, 100, 400);
Flasher led2(15, 350, 350);
Flasher led3(16, 100, 400);
Flasher led4(17, 350, 350);

#define buzzer 13
#define greenled 20
#define redled 21
#define Password_Length 5

char  buffers[4][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4'}, {'6', '5', '4', '3'}, {'9', '8', '7', '6'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6'}}; // this is how to initialise a 2d array
unsigned long previousMillis[5]; //[x] = number of leds
byte i, x, y;
char Data[Password_Length]; // 6 is the number of chars it can hold + the null char = 7

byte data_count = 0;
bool Pass_is_good;
char customKey;
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
int ledservos[4] = {14, 15, 16, 17};
Keypad customKeypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); //initialize an instance of class NewKeypad

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT);
  Serial.print("Enter Password");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  led1.Update();
  customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  if (customKey) {
    // makes sure a key is actually pressed, equal to (customKey != NO_KEY)
    Data[data_count] = customKey; // store char into data array
    data_count++; // increment data array by 1 to store new char, also keep track of the number of chars entered
  }
  if (data_count == Password_Length - 1) {
    // if the array index is equal to the number of expected chars, compare data to master
    Serial.print("Password is ");
    for (byte i = 0; i < Password_Length; i++)
      Serial.print(Data[i]);
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      //this loop for number of passwords in the array
      for (y = 0; y < 4; y ++) {
        //this loop for number of characters in each of the password array
        if (strcmp(Data[y], buffers[x][y]) != 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (y == 4) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (x < 4) {
      Serial.print(" Found at index ");
      Serial.println(x);
      switch (x) {
        case 0:
          led2.Update();
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(16, LOW);
          digitalWrite(17, LOW);
          break;
        case 1:
          led3.Update();
          digitalWrite(15, LOW);
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(17, LOW);
          break;
        case 2:
          led4.Update();
          digitalWrite(15, LOW);
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(16, LOW);
          break;
        case 3:
          digitalWrite(15, LOW);
          digitalWrite(14, LOW);
          digitalWrite(16, LOW);
          digitalWrite(17, LOW);
          break;
      }
    }
    clearData();
  }
}

void clearData() {
  Serial.println();
  while (data_count != 0) {
    // This can be used for any array size,
    Data[data_count--] = 0; //clear array for new data
  }
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: why don't you try to determine  why all the LEDs start flashing when the program starts

Comment: actually ia m trying to get help cz totally stuck after this step

Comment: look at the first command in the loop() block .....  think about its function

Comment: dear i understand what u r meaning,but when i tried to put led.blink function in the switch cases i did not get any reults ,though they r supposed to work there

Comment: Put a link to the TimedBlink library you are using In your question, not in a reply to an answer. You need to provide enough information for the people reading your question to be able to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Now that you added a link to the TimedBlink library I was able to go look at it. That is not a very well written library, and its documentation is **horrible**.

It seems that `blink(int,int)` starts a TimedBlink LED blinking, and blinkOff stops it. So you should not call `LEDx.blink(150,50)` on any of your LEDs until you want them to start blinking.

You need to refactor your code to only call `LEDx.blink(150,50)` on one LED at a time. You probably want your switch statement to call `LEDx.blink(150,50)` on the LED that you want to blink and ledOff() on the others.

Comment: thank u 4 ur reply,
this is the link for the timed blink
[link](https://github.com/lpasqualis/TimedBlink),
i have tried the suggested way in  ur answer but it did not work ,the leds remain off

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You need to edit your question and provide the link to the library in the question, not buried in a comment to my answer. Other people reading this thread will want the same information and they should not have to hunt for it. When you are getting ready to post a question, stop and think: “What information will the readers of my question need in order to understand my question? Have I provided everything?”

Comment: i have tried that but unfortunately no result